# Why is $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\frac{dt}{dx}\ne\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I'm confused why the following is not equal.

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\frac{dt}{dx}\ne\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)^2$$

I thought those should be equal by canceling out terms as if handling plain variables.

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\frac{dt}{dx}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\times\frac{dt^2}{dx^2}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

However it is easy to find a counterexample. If $x=t^2$ and $y=e^t$,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{e^t}{2t}\right)\frac{1}{2t}=\frac{2te^t-2e^t}{4t^2}\times\frac{1}{2t}=\frac{e^t}{4t^2}\times\frac{t-1}{t}$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^t\right)\left(\frac{1}{2t}\right)^2=e^t\times\frac{1}{4t^2}=\frac{e^t}{4t^2}$$

I know handling $dx$ as a plain variable doesn't always work, but I'd like to know why exactly it doesn't *work* in this case.

Comment: $(\frac {dt} {dx})^{2} =\frac {dt^{2}}{dx^{2}}$?

Comment: @geetha290krm Is $dx^2$ different from $(dx)^2$?

Comment: Use a simple example $z=(t^2)(x^2)$ Remember to work from the inside out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange the equation to:

$$\frac d{dt} \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}\neq \frac d{dt} \frac{dy}{dt}$$

By the chain rule
$$\frac{dy}{dt}= \frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}$$ so the RHS  follows the product rule:

$$\frac d{dt}\frac{dy}{dt}= \frac d{dt}\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt} +\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac d{dt}\frac{dx}{dt} $$

The second term is missing from the LHS of rearranged unequality.

This would also be remedied starting from LHS by writing

$$\frac d{dt} \frac {dy}{dx} = \frac d{dt} \left(\frac{dy}{dt}/\frac{dx}{dt}\right)$$

and applying quotient/product rule.

Of the two question-marked equations in OP, the first is OK. The problem with the second is that the derivative of the chain rule requires applying the product rule, which introduces multiple terms, thus treating higher derivatives like ratios doesn’t really work out the same way it does for first derivatives.

Writing $x=g(t), y=f(x) = (f\circ g)(t)$, the second question-marked equation should correctly be:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}
&=(f\circ g)’’(t)\\
&= ((f’\circ g)(t) \cdot g’(t) )’\\
&= (f’’\circ g)(t) \cdot g’(t)^2 + (f’\circ g)(t) g’’(t)\\
&= \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{dx^2}{dt^2} + \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

but the second term is missing in OP.

Comment: The second equation in the question, when expanded correctly, starts with $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$ and ends with $\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}\times\frac{dt^2}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dt}\times\frac{d^2 t}{dx^2}$, but the same logic applies. Then there's [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705579/why-cant-we-cancel-out-dt2) why canceling out $dt^2$ is not okay while canceling out $dt$ is okay.