# Why can't we "cancel out" $dt^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

When $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$, we can write

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\times\frac{dt}{dx}$$

as if $dt$ is "canceled out".

However, I recently noticed that canceling out $dt^2$ (not $d(t^2)$) can be problematic. In the following,

$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\times\frac{dt}{dx}\right)\\
=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\frac{dt}{dx}+\frac{dy}{dt}\times\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)\\
=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\frac{dt^2}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dt}\times\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)\\
=\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}\times\frac{dt^2}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dt}\times\frac{d^2 t}{dx^2}$$

we cannot cancel out $dt^2$ because

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}&=\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}\times\frac{dt^2}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dt}\times\frac{d^2 t}{dx^2}\\&\ne\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dt}\times\frac{d^2 t}{dx^2}\end{aligned}$$

Why is canceling out $dt^2$ not okay?

Comment: The quick answer is that the notation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is misleading. If you actually calculate it then $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})=\frac{d^2ydx-d^2xdy}{dx^3}$ The reason for the discrepancy is that for the purposes of the notation $d^2x$ is assumed to be identiacally zero. Whether these sorts of calculations are reasonable is a seperate issue that I won't get into. In short Leibniz notation can be misleading if you don't know how to use it and this is exactly the issue present here.

Comment: Also the notation $\frac{d t^2}{d x^2 }$ is not correct. It is $\left(\frac{d t}{d x}\right)^2$. This cannot be handled like an ordinary fraction of two numbers.

Comment: Try to justify your manipulations using the explicit and entirely unambiguous "prime" notation. This will require the introduction of more (inverse) functions, but is worthwhile because it can never tempt you into making a mistake. Fishbane's comment is a perfect observation

Answer (score 1):

According to the chain rule, only the outermost derivative in an expression can be “canceled.”

You can cancel one of the $dt$, but it’s not possible to “cancel” twice in a row because, by canceling the first $dt$, the variable of the outermost derivative has been exchanged to be $dx$.

—

In more detail:

The chain rule says that $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$$ and in all cases “canceling” actually just means applying this rule. To apply the chain rule, the expression must be of the form $f’(g(x))g’(x)$ for some functions $f$ and $g$. If so, then “canceling” is possible, otherwise not.

So why doesn’t cancellation work in the case OP asked? There can be just one answer: Because its not of the form of the RHS of chain rule.

It is possible to cancel one of the $dt$ though:

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} \frac{dt}{dx} =
\frac{dy’}{dt}  \frac{dt}{dx} = 
\frac{dy’}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}
$$

Here we have recognized that $$
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} \frac{dt}{dx} =f’(g(x))g’(x)$$ for $f(t) = y’(t)$ and $g(x) =t(x)$, and thus that we may apply the chain rule.

So why can’t we apply the chain rule yet again to cancel another $dt$? Consider the expression

$$\frac{dt}{dx} \frac{dy’}{dx}=\frac{dt}{dx} \frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Yes there are two $dt$’s—but there is another operator $\frac d{dx}$ in between them. If we want to apply the chain rule again, we need to find $h(t)$ such that: $$h’(t(x)) = (y’(t(x)))’ = y’’(t(x))t’(x)$$ which is hopeless since only the left hand side is independent of $t’$.

If $\frac{dt}{dx}$ and $\frac d{dx}$ would *commute* (if we could switch their order) then we could apply the chain rule and OP’s formula would be correct:

$$\frac{dt}{dx} \frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}\overset{?}= \frac{d}{dx} \frac{dt}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

But we know this is not the case—to move a function inside a derivative operator you have to use the product rule $$fD(g) = D(fg) - D(f)g$$ which has an extra term. Applying the product rule like this we get the corrected formula:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} \frac{dt}{dx}^2
&= 
\frac{dt}{dx} \frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}\\
&=\frac d{dx}\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}\right) - \frac{d^2t}{dx^2}\frac{dy}{dt}\\
&=
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{d^2t}{dx^2}\frac{dy}{dt}
\end{align*}
$$
(By the way, this version of the product rule is also called the Leibniz identity and written as a commutator of operators $[D,f] = D(f)$.)

Comment: I re-edited your last edit on the OP since you removed a term in the result. Please let me know if it was intentional. Also in your last equation, what is happening between the first line and the second line?

Comment: Its just the product rule but in the form $f g’ = (fg)’ -f’g$.

Comment: Its also called the leibniz identity and written $[d,f] = df$. In that case $d$ is derivative operator, $f$ is operator of multiplying by a function, and brackets are commutator. For a test function $g$, it says $d(f\cdot g) - f\cdot dg = (df)\cdot g$ or the product rule